# rails redirect_to - при указании action параметр notice передается как GET-параметр

Tags: ruby-on-rails

В контроллере Users (сгенерированном generate scaffold_controller) в методе Update есть такой стандартный код:

```
format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
```

Как и положено, происходит редирект и на странице отображается сообщение из параметра notice
Мне надо сделать редирект на другой action, поэтому я изменил код так:

```
format.html { redirect_to action: 'index', notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
```

В этом случае редирект происходит на нужную страницу, но notice отображается как GET-параметр в url. Например, /users?notice=User+was+successfully+updated. Сообщения на странице нет.
ВОПРОС: подскажите, как передать настроить редирект на нужный action и при этом notice работал корректно.
Важно редиректить именно указывая action, так как у меня два контроллера для одной модели и стандартные хелперы ведут на actions другого контроллера.

Answer (score 0):

`redirect_to` [принимает два параметра](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to), и первый из них может быть практически чем угодно (хэшом, сущностью, строкой или блоком), а второй - только хэшом. В вашей нотации метод воспринимает оба параметра как хэш и на их основании строит ссылку для редиректа через `url_for`. Если вы добавите к этой нотации границы первого хэша, то всё заработает.

```
format.html { 
  redirect_to({action: 'index'}, notice: 'User was successfully updated.') 
}
```

Но вообще можно воспользоваться и хелпером, в другом вашем вопросе я чуть подробнее ответила про них

```
format.html { redirect_to admin_users_path, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
```